# how can i get the height of UILabel?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

hello everyone,
              Here i took one UIView and UIScrollview from storyboard and set its constraint from storyboard and i have created one UILabel programmatically inside of UIView and set its constraint. Now my problem is how can i get the height of UILabel? so based on its height i want to calculate the height of UIView and also need to set content size of scrollview.

Here is my code

```
UIViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrlview;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *my_view;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightconstraint;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lbl_title;

@end


UIViewController.m 

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrlview,my_view,heightconstraint,lbl_title;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title=@"Demo";
    NSString *text3 = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non quam ac massa viverra semper. Maecenas mattis justo ac augue volutpat congue. Maecenas laoreet, nulla eu faucibus gravida, felis orci dictum risus, sed sodales sem eros eget risus. Morbi imperdiet sed diam et sodales. Vestibulum ut est id mauris ultrices gravida. Nulla malesuada metus ut erat malesuada, vitae ornare neque semper. Aenean a commodo justo, vel placerat odio. Curabitur vitae consequat tortor. Aenean eu magna ante. Integer tristique elit ac augue laoreet, eget pulvinar lacus dictum. Cras eleifend lacus eget pharetra elementum. Etiam fermentum eu felis eu tristique. Integer eu purus vitae turpis blandit consectetur. Nulla facilisi. Praesent bibendum massa eu metus pulvinar, quis tristique nunc commodo. Ut varius aliquam elit, a tincidunt elit aliquam non. Nunc ac leo purus. Proin condimentum placerat ligula, at tristique neque scelerisque ut. Suspendisse ut";



    lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    [lbl_title setText:text3];
    [lbl_title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0f]];
    [lbl_title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [lbl_title setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
    lbl_title.numberOfLines=0;
    [my_view addSubview:lbl_title];

    [my_view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl_title

                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading

                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual

                                                                    toItem:my_view

                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading

                                                                multiplier:1.0

                                                                  constant:10.0]];



    [my_view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl_title

                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop

                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual

                                                                    toItem:my_view

                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop

                                                                multiplier:1.0

                                                                  constant:10.0]];





    [my_view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl_title

                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing

                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual

                                                                    toItem:my_view

                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing

                                                                multiplier:1.0

                                                                  constant:-10.0]];

NSLog(@"height of label in viewdidload %f",lbl_title.frame.size.height);
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    NSLog(@"height of label %f",lbl_title.frame.size.height);
   [scrlview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 2000)];
   heightconstraint.constant=2000;
}
```

Comment: Use `[label sizeToFit];` after assigning Text to the Label, you frame should work fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the autolayout then you have to use `layoutIfNeeded`. to get the frame of all `SubView`

```
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
NSLog(@"height of label %f",lbl_title.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
    label_getTextSize = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 28, 296, 59)];
    label_getTextSize.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label_getTextSize.numberOfLines = 3;
    
    CGSize labelSize = [label_getTextSize textHeigh:someText attributes:[self getTextStyle]];

=================
-(NSDictionary *) getTextStyle
{
    UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:10];
    float lineSpacing = 0.0f;
    float kerling = 0.0f;
    
    
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragrahStyle setLineSpacing:lineSpacing];
    
    NSDictionary * textAttributes = @{
                                NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                NSKernAttributeName : @(kerling),
                                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragrahStyle
                                };
    
    return textAttributes;
}
```

Comment: Yuri thank you for replaying but read first my question ... i am using aulayout constraint.

Comment: label_getTextSize = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XX,XX,lbl_title.frame.width,xx)]; XX - any value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to init with a frame for the UILabel `lbl_title`. So instead of using

```
lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc]init];
```

use

```
lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:];
```